# What will be the angular velocity of a line about a line that is at some angle with the plane of motion?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

In [this book](https://archive.org/details/engineeringmech100meri/page/322/mode/2up) it is written that angular velocity of a rigid body is time derivate of "angular displacement" of any line in the plane of motion of the body. The angular position of the line is measured from any conveniently fixed reference axis *in the plane of motion.*
For example in the figure shown below, the authors have chosen the horizontal line to be the reference axis. The angular positions of lines $1$ and $2$ are $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$ respectively.

[image]

I don't understand how this can be the definition used to find the angular velocity of the lines (1 and 2), which move in the plane, from a reference line that make some angle to the plane of motion. What will be angular positions for lines 1 and 2, from this angled reference axis? What is angular displacement?

For concrete example suppose in the figure below I take $OM$ as reference axis and I want to find the angular velocity of the line $OP$ that is rotating anticlockwise maintaining the same height $PM$ and $NP$ (although they don't look to be the same in my very bad drawing). In starting $OM$ and $OP$ makes angle $\alpha$ at some time and then after infinitesimal seconds later the line moves and now makes angle $\beta$ with the line $OM$.
So should the angular displacement be $\beta -\alpha$? This seems very wired; how is this difference related to the rotation?
[image: sketch]

I have read many books on this topic but they all give the same definition which involves the reference axis to be in the plane of motion. It seems that we can't take any line as a reference axis.

Comment: Yes you can take any line as reference. It is the change in angle of a line in the body. Take a line in the body, any line. Measure how much it’s angle changes. That change tells you how much angular displacement there was. The reference line is meaningless. It’s just a base, in order to have two numbers to subtract for calculating the difference

Comment: Of course the line may have moved. We are measuring its angle. And how much its angle changes. Change in its angle from vertical, in its angle from horizontal, in its angle from a 45-line. Change in its angle. Thats angular displacement

Comment: There. Ok sorry not *any* line: any line in the plane of the moving line can be the reference line. But you dont need a reference line. Can take the line that has moved in a plane and measure angle between before motion and after motion.

Comment: @Al Brown So we cant define the angular velocity of $OP$ with respect to $OM?$

Comment: I edited that can you refresh one last time? Had a mistake

Comment: You can always define any axis and get different rotation. I thought this was about the center of mass. Where translation is defined and then remainder is rotation. If not then I think I accidentally wasted some of your time.

Comment: Is it calculating omega about the center of mass or is it about selecting different axes as the defined axis of rotation?

Comment: We need an axis to have an angular position of another line, but as you point out we don't need a reference axis for defining angular velocity. Angular velocity is the derivative of angular displacement wrt to time. Angular displacement is the angle made between a line at two instants.

Comment: Ok. Is it calculating Theta around center of mass or around a given axis of rotation?

Comment: But for the sake of simplicity, we choose the reference axis (for defining the angular position of a line), such that it lies in the plane of motion. **If we do** so **then** the angular displacement can also be taught as a change in angular position. But in my case, we can take the line $OM$ for defining the angular potion of the other line **only**, but we can't use the difference in angle ($\beta -\alpha$) *in this case,* to be angular displacement, as it is the angle made between the line $OP$ at the two instances which is not equal to $\beta -\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

If a solid object is rotating about fixed axle, all points (and lines) in that object will circle the axle in the same period of time. (They have the same angular velocity.)

Comment: I don't see how this directly answers the question. I am asking if I can take the line $OM$ as a reference axis for defining the angular velocity of the other line. Thanks.

Comment: Try picturing your reference axis as an axle with the other lines as being within a solid object.